# The sum of the elements in a field of at least three elements is 0

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This statement seems so simple yet I don't quite know how to start with this proof in a substantial way.  Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Is your question how to prove the statement "If $F$ is a field such that $|F| \geq 3$, then the sum of all elements of $F$ is $0$"?  Also, is $F$ any field?  Are there any restrictions on $F$, such as if it is a finite field, or countable, etc.?

Comment: One idea: since every non-zero element has an *additive* inverse, and addition is commutative, for any finite field $F$, each non-zero element added with its unique additive inverse will result in $0$.  But this is true for any finite ring.

Comment: Also, one more comment: I noticed that you ask many questions, but have not accepted any "best" answers.  If you do receive a response that fully answers your question, you should accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.  Some users may be wary of answering a question if they see that the asker never accepts any answer on their questions.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot But in characteristic $2$, each element is its own additive inverse. That's the case where something needs to be shown. (And of course, the field needs to be finite.)

Comment: Of course, you mean "a **finite** field with at least three elements", right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To even speak of a sum, I suppose the field $F$ is finite. If $f\colon F\to F$ is any bijection, then we can conclude that $\sum_{x\in F}x=\sum_{x\in F}f(x)$. Let $\alpha\in F$ such that $\alpha\ne 0$. Then $x\mapsto \alpha x$ is such a bijection. We conclude that $\sum_{x\in F} x=\sum_{x\in F}\alpha x$, i.e. $(1-\alpha)\sum x=0$. If $F$ has more than two elements, we can pick $\alpha\in F\setminus\{0,1\}$ and are done.

---

To elaborate:

Why does $\sum_{x\in F}x=\sum_{x\in F}f(x)$ hold if $f\colon F\to F$ is a bijection? More generally, if $I$ is any finite set and for each $i\in I$, $a_i$ is a number (or element of an additive abelian group such as $F$), and $f\colon I\to I$ is a bijection, then $\sum_{i\in I} a_i = \sum_{i\in I}a_{f(i)}$. This is because the summands on the right are precisely the same summnds as on the left and hence equality is guaranteed by the laws of associativity and commutativity. *(I suppose this rough reference to merely changed order of addition suffices; otherwise a formal proof is possible by induction based on the fact that the group of permutations of $I$ is generated by transpositions ("swappng two adjacent elements"))*

After this, if $F$ has more than two elements, it certainly has more elements than only $0$ and $1$. Therefore there exixts $\alpha$ that is both $\ne0$ and $\ne 1$. With such $\alpha$ the key steps in the proof above work.
The first condition, $\alpha\ne 0$,  guarantees that the map $F\to F$, $x\mapsto \alpha x$ is a bijection (namely with $x\mapsto \alpha^{-1}x$ as inverse map) and so allows us to conclude than $(1-\alpha)\sum_{x\in F} x=0$.
The second condition $\alpha\ne 1$, allows us to conclude that the first factor $(1-\alpha)$ is nonzero, hence the second factor must be zero, i.e. $\sum_{x\in F} x=0$ as was to be shown.

Comment: how do you justify the bijection part?  And also can you explain in more detail how if F has more than two elements we can just pick and we're done?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

If $\;\Bbb F\;$ is a finite field, then there exists a prime $\;p\;$ such that $\;\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ is the prime subfield of $\;\Bbb F\;$, so that $\;|\Bbb F|=p^n\;$ , for some $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$.

But then we know, if we denote by $\;\overline{\Bbb F_p}\;$ an algebraic closure of the prime field, that:

$$\Bbb F=\left\{a\in\overline{\Bbb F_p}\;:\;\;a^{p^n}-a=0\right\}=\left\{a\in\overline{\Bbb F_p}\;;\;a\;\;\text{is a root of}\;\;x^{p^n}-x\in\Bbb F_p[x]\right\}$$

and then the sum of all elements in $\;\Bbb F\;$ is the coefficient of$\;x^{p^n-1}\;$ in the above polynomial....

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different proof which does not use the field structure of a general $\mathbb F_q$ at all. Instead I will show with just basic linear algebra and tiny combinatorics that, if $V$ is any $n$-dimensional $\mathbb F_p$-vector space, then

$$\sum_{v \in V} v = 0$$

unless $p=2$ and $n=1$.

Namely, say $e_1, ..., e_n$ is a basis of $V$, then an arbitrary element $v \in V$ is written as $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$ with *unique* $a_i \in \mathbb F_p$. Then a moment's consideration shows that for each $i \in \{1, ...,n\}$ and $j= \bar 0, \bar 1, ..., \overline{p-1} \in \mathbb F_p$, there are exactly $p^{n-1}$ elements $v \in V$ such that  $a_i = j$. So the coefficient of $e_i$ in $\sum_{v \in V} v$ is the residue mod $p$ of

$$p^{n-1} \cdot (1+2+...(p-1)) = p^{n-1}\cdot \frac{(p-1)p}{2} = p^n \cdot \frac{p-1}{2}$$

which obviously is divisible by $p$, except in the case that simultaneously $n=1$ and $p=2$.